What's the proper name for combinator λ x . λ y . x (x) = S(S(K(S))(K))(K)
What is the proper name for combinator
$$λ x . λ y . x (x) = S(S(K(S))(K))(K) = SBK \text { ?}$$ I call it dbl and I noticed that it's half a quine.
But I would like to refer to it by some established name, if there's any.

Having read through To Mock A Mockingbird, I found no established name for this combinator, even though it does appear in an exercise or two. It's referred to as C(KM) which is no shorter than SBK presented in the OP.
